# How to create a service based in a WSDL of another service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am really new in services and are having some problems with one issue. The fact is, i have a WSDL of a SAP system and i need to create a Web API in Visual Studio based on it.

I passed some time searching for tutorial's of how to do that but don't have lucky. Someone would help me, explaining the concept or sending some tutorial where i could understand how to do that? I am completely lost and i need it for my job.

If anyone could help me i would stay quite grateful. Thank you everyone for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just host the WSDL in ur IIS  i.e Create an application in IIS pointing to the directly that contains the WSDL.

And add service reference to the WSDL by pointing to the IIS Url of the application.

Then in config, change it to point to actual implementation of the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `WSDL` of the service you might be able to use [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate your `WCF` client proxy with all the required contracts for it. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905.aspx) is another link on generation and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950598/920557) with an example, plus another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39259530/920557).

Comment: Thank you Eugene. I will try here and will say you if worked soon.