# Need to create service interface class for WCF service.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

Here is a snippet of the code file I am trying to generate. This is an older WCF project, so I am not familiar. With the new service projects I simply right click and choose update service references.

```
using System;
`//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.269
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", 
"4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = 
"IBusinessService")]
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public interface IBusinessService
{

[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IBusinessService/Receive_Replenishment_Request", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IBusinessService/Receive_Replenishment_RequestResponse")]
int Receive_Replenishment_Request(System.Nullable<int> Module, System.Nullable<int> Level, System.Nullable<int> Side, System.Nullable<int> Row, string User);
```

This file is in a separate project than the BusinessService.cs and IBuesinessService.cs which has the [ServiceContract] attribute.

Is there a tool that I have to run to generate the service reference class? I need to update this service reference.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want to generate the interface which defines the service? Or do you want to generate the consumer code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the "Add Service Reference" window is a mere wrapper for [Svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) (or they call into the same APIs). You can execute that tool from a command prompt.

If your service you want to generate a client for actually runs and exposes metadata, it's as simple as

```
svcutil http://service/metadataEndpoint
```

To generate the "proxy", the classes and data types that form the service client.

If you can't run the service, or if it can't expose metadata, I guess you need to export metadata from the assembly containing the service to .wsdl and .xsd files:

```
svcutil.exe ServiceAssembly.dll
```

Then generate a client from those files:

```
svcutil.exe YourServiceName.wsdl
```

See also [How to generate WCF service with SvcUtil.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997821/how-to-generate-wcf-service-with-svcutil-exe).

Comment: So it looks like this is not a true service reference, but just an interface. And I am not sure how it was created before? Will this svcutil create an interface file?

Comment: I've changed the second sentence in my answer. Yes, Svcutil.exe will generate an interface representing the service, and a proxy class that acts as a client to that service.